# wso2 carbon - how to log the soap messages to the console with log4j

Tags: wso2

I would like to dump the soap requests and responses to the console.

I have tried setting up log4:

```
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire=DEBUG, CARBON_CONSOLE
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.httpclient=DEBUG, CARBON_CONSOLE
```

However, this isn't logging any soap requests/responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with Log4J properties. I enabled TRACE for like following,

log4j.logger.org.apache.axis2.builder=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter=TRACE

Still you can't get the SOAP messages going in and out. If you're playing around with ESB then of course you can use the Log mediator in inSequence and outSequence to get the SOAP request/response

Easiest way would be to use a tool like TCPMon (shipped with all the WSO2 products and can be found in the bin folder) or SOAP UI.

Comment: I'm trying to debug an issue that is only happening with local transports so using an interceptor will not work for me.  I've created a JIRA in the upstream AXIS2 project (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-5580)

Comment: Chris, you can compile the Axis2 version that's shipped with the WSO2 product that you're trying and then debug Axis2 code to find out the incoming message format. For example, WSO2 AppServer 5.0.1 use this version of Axis2 - http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.0.0/dependencies/axis2/1.6.1-wso2v9. Then put a debug point on invokeBusinessLogic() in RPCMessageReceiver.java and do remote debugging. Here's a screenshot - http://i.imgur.com/xt1VbgQ.png

Comment: thanks, was doing earlier though my development environment isn't setup properly, so it was a bit painful.  Also, sometimes it's nice to stand back to look at the soap messages.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the logging in wso2 might help.
Go to Configure->Logging, and set the org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver, org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender, org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalResponder to the DEBUG level.
It will end up in the in the repository/logs/wso2carbon.log